# Use microphone over LAN? (PulseAudio probably)

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I need software on Machine A to use the microphone on Machine B as if it was a microphone on Machine A. Both run Linux (RHEL and OpenSUSE respectively) and both use PulseAudio.

I did find a few hints about playing sound from Machine A on Machine B. But I want to use the microphone and not play sound, and I can' really find anything.

So how do I connect the microphone on Machine B to make it work as if it was local to Machine A?

Advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT: importantly. pulseaudio-module-zeroconf is unfortunately not available for RHEL/CentOS 8. This means I need to configure the client without using zeroconf/avahi.

Comment: The exactly same way as playing sound.

Comment: @IporSircer unfortunately, I have no pulseaudio-module-zeroconf (edited the question to reflect this). And all non-zeroconf example strings I can find are output-only, for example:  $ pactl load-module module-tunnel-sink "server=192.168.254.20 sink=alsa_output.platform-1c22c00.codec.analog-stereo sink_name=cubietruck"

Comment: Using another machines microphone : that is nontrivial if it is to be done securely (one reason why it is unusual.)

Comment: I have no need for security in this case. The service is to be enabled for short runs for audio tests (noise passage). If someone were to hack into this microphone, they will hear some howling and be able to calculate the noise frequency response, which I post on an open forum anyway.

Comment: Do you have [module-rtp-send](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#rtpsdpsaptransport)?